# How to reload UIInputViewController in iOS8 Keyboard Extension?

Tags: ios8, uiinputviewcontroller

I need to reload my custom keyboard in `iOS8` Custom Keyboard `Extension`.

I have color preferences that can change keyboard background color.

```
[self reloadInputView];
```

Above codes is doesn't work and not reload.

So how can i reload `UIInputViewController` in `iOS8`?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should call setter method on main thread, you can have a try. such as...
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            //write the codes here to set property that can cause UI change... })